# Camel Hystrix EIP - IgnoreExceptions to prevent call to Fallback

Tags: java, apache-camel, hystrix

In Apache camel Hystrix EIP, how can we prevent the call to fallback method for bad request exception. I tried throwing "HystrixBadRequestException" from my request dispatcher processor, but I still see that fallback is getting triggered. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
 /* in route builder class */
public void configure() throws Exception {
    .hystrix()
        .hystrixConfiguration()
        .circuitBreakerEnabled(circuitBreakerConfig.isEnabled())
        .executionTimeoutInMilliseconds(circuitBreakerConfig.getConnectionTimeoutInMilliseconds())
        .circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage(circuitBreakerConfig.getErrorThresholdPercentage())
        .circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds(circuitBreakerConfig.getSleepWindowInMilliseconds())
        .circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold(circuitBreakerConfig.getRequestVolumeThreshold())
        .metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds(circuitBreakerConfig.getRollingPercentileWindowInMilliseconds())
        .end()
            .to("requestDispatcher")
        .onFallback()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Fallback:")
            .bean("responsehandler", "getFallbackResponse")
            .stop()
        .end()
}
    /* in dispatcher class */
private Exchange dispatchRequest(Exchange exchange) {
    if (exception instanceof HttpOperationFailedException) {
        Integer statusCode = ((HttpOperationFailedException) exception).getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 400) {
            throw new HystrixBadRequestException("Hystrix bad request");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not implemented in camel-hystrix. I have logged a ticket to get this added in upcoming releases: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13066